# AR with OpenCV & OpenGL

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, augmented-reality

Here's the problem: I wrote a code to display the OpenGL teapot on a sheet of paper with drawing. For this, I track the 4 corners of the paper (using SURF detection & matching followed by computing the homography matrix, then moving average of the corners position to reduce the jitter). The corners coordinates are used to compute the intrinsic & extrinsic matrices of the camera (using `calibrateCamera()` and `solvePnP()`, respectively). The rotation matrix is then computed using `Rodrigues()`. Afterwards, I computed the rotation angles using `decomposeProjectionMatrix()`. Here's the OpenCV part of the code:

```
...
objPoints.push_back(objCorners);
scenePoints.push_back(sceneCorners);
calibrateCamera(objPoints, scenePoints, Size(640,480), camMtx, distortCoeff, RVecs, tVecs);
solvePnP(objCorners, sceneCorners, camMtx, distortCoeff, RVec, tVec);
Rodrigues(RVec, rotMtx);
getAngles(rotMtx, rotAngles);
```

`objCorners` are the corners coordinates in the template image ([1 1], [img width 1], [img width img height], [1 img height]). sceneCorners are the corners coordinates in the webcam frame, computed using the homography matrix. The function `getAngles()` is as follows:

```
void getAngles(Mat &rotCamMtx, Vec3d &angles)
{
    Mat camMtx, rotMtx, transVec, rotMtxX, rotMtxY, rotMtxZ;
    double  *r = rotCamMtx.ptr<double>();
    double projMtx[12] = {r[0], r[1], r[2], 0, 
                          r[3], r[4], r[5], 0, 
                          r[6], r[7], r[8], 0};

    decomposeProjectionMatrix(Mat(3,4,CV_64FC1,projMtx), camMtx, rotMtx, transVec, rotMtxX, rotMtxY, rotMtxZ, angles);
}
```

Then I set the element of the OpenGL model view matrix as follows:

```
modelViewMat[0]  = 1.0;
modelViewMat[1]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[2]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[3]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[4]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[5]  = 1.0;
modelViewMat[6]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[7]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[8]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[9]  = 0.0;
modelViewMat[10] = 1.0;
modelViewMat[11] = 0.0;
modelViewMat[12] = 2*matCenter.x/639 - 641/639;
modelViewMat[13] = 481/479 - 2*matCenter.y/479;
modelViewMat[14] = -0.25;
modelViewMat[15] = 1.0;
```

`matCenter` is the center coordinate of the paper, obtained by taking the average of the 4 corners. The values in `modelViewMat[12]` and `modelViewMat[13]` are obtained by mapping the pixel coordinates ([1 640], [1 480]) to ([-1 1], [1 -1]). The OpenGL part of the code:

```
...
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixd(modelViewMat);

glRotated(-45, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotated(rotAngles[2], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glutSolidTeapot(0.3);
```

I rotated the teapot -45 degrees around x-axis to make it appears "sitting" on the paper.
The result is this: if I translate the paper on the desk, the location of the teapot on the paper is more or less correct (on the same spot). If I rotate the paper, the teapot will follow the rotation correctly (around y-axis), but the location is no more correct. The question is: how to "pin" the teapot always on the same spot of the paper? I've tried using the result of `Rodrigues()` and `solvePnP()` directly in the OpenGL model view matrix (as suggested in [OpenCV + OpenGL: proper camera pose using solvePnP](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23089/opencv-opengl-proper-camera-pose-using-solvepnp/)), but the result is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem several days ago, based on the code from http://blog.yarrago.com/2011/08/introduction-to-augmented-reality.html. To display the 3D object correctly, the OpenGL projection matrix is set first, followed by the OpenGL model view matrix. The elements of the projection matrix are computed from the intrinsic matrix of the camera as follows:

```
calibrateCamera(objPoints, scenePoints, Size(640,480), camMtx, distortCoeff, RVecs, tVecs);
...
projectionMat[0]  = 2*camMtx.at<double>(0,0)/frameW;
projectionMat[1]  = 0;
projectionMat[2]  = 0;
projectionMat[3]  = 0;
projectionMat[4]  = 0;
projectionMat[5]  = 2*camMtx.at<double>(1,1)/frameH;
projectionMat[6]  = 0;
projectionMat[7]  = 0;
projectionMat[8]  = 1 - 2*camMtx.at<double>(0,2)/frameW;
projectionMat[9]  = -1 + (2*camMtx.at<double>(1,2) + 2)/frameH;
projectionMat[10] = (zNear + zFar)/(zNear - zFar);
projectionMat[11] = -1;
projectionMat[12] = 0;
projectionMat[13] = 0;
projectionMat[14] = 2*zNear*zFar/(zNear - zFar);
projectionMat[15] = 0;
```

`frameW` and `frameH` are `640` and `480`, respectively. `zNear` is `0.1` and `zFar` is `100`.

The elements of the OpenGL model view matrix are computed from the rotation matrix and the translation vector (obtained from `solvePnP()` and `Rodrigues()`). To get a correct positioning of the 3D object, the translation vector needs to be transformed before computing the model view matrix.

```
// Offset value to move the translation vector
double offsetC[3][1] = {424, 600, 0};
Mat    offset(3, 1, CV_64F, offsetC);
...
solvePnP(objCorners, sceneCorners, camMtx, distortCoeff, RVec, tVec);
Rodrigues(RVec, rotMtx);
tVec = tVec + rotMtx*offset;    // Move tVec to refer to the center of the paper
tVec = tVec / 250.0;            // Converting pixel coordinates to OpenGL world coordinates
...
modelviewMat[0]  = rotMtx.at<double>(0,0);
modelviewMat[1]  = -rotMtx.at<double>(1,0);
modelviewMat[2]  = -rotMtx.at<double>(2,0);
modelviewMat[3]  = 0;
modelviewMat[4]  = rotMtx.at<double>(0,1);
modelviewMat[5]  = -rotMtx.at<double>(1,1);
modelviewMat[6]  = -rotMtx.at<double>(2,1);
modelviewMat[7]  = 0;
modelviewMat[8]  = rotMtx.at<double>(0,2);
modelviewMat[9]  = -rotMtx.at<double>(1,2);
modelviewMat[10] = -rotMtx.at<double>(2,2);
modelviewMat[11] = 0;
modelviewMat[12] = tVec.at<double>(0,0);
modelviewMat[13] = -tVec.at<double>(1,0);
modelviewMat[14] = -tVec.at<double>(2,0);
modelviewMat[15] = 1;
```

The numerical values for `offsetC` is the pixel coordinate of the center of the paper. The OpenGL part of the code is then:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(projectionMat);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(modelviewMat);

glRotatef(90, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);  // Rotate the teapot first so that it will be displayed correctly on the paper
glutSolidTeapot(1.0);
```

One important thing for the correct positioning of the teapot is the transformation of `tVec`.